# Sublime Text API event when tmLanguage file is

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there an event that I can hook into for when a tmLanguage file is used on the current file opened in the Sublime Text Plugin API?

I have this project https://github.com/samholmes/EJS.tmLanguage and I have this issue https://github.com/samholmes/EJS.tmLanguage/issues/7#issuecomment-37764728

What I need is to be able to run some code when a file is opened in Sublime that is an EJS file. This way I can check a variable to see which of the two tmLanguage files was last used and call set_syntax_file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See `sublime_plugin.EventListener#on_load` in the [ST2](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and [ST3](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) docs. You may also be interested in `Settings#add_on_change`. Though you can solve stuff in your plugin, you may also want to suggest [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) to your users as a more generic solution.